# Algebraic Integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ and Norms on them

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm having a problem with a section of Niven's book the Theory Of Numbers.  I am trying to show:

If an integer $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ is neither zero nor a unit, prove that $|N(\alpha)|>1$.

An element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ would look like $a+b\sqrt{m}$ where $a,b$ are rational integers $0, \pm1, \pm2,...$  The norm is defined as $N(\alpha)=\alpha\bar{\alpha}$, where $\bar{\alpha}$ is defined as the conjugate of $\alpha$ ($\alpha=a+b\sqrt{m}, \bar{\alpha}=a-b\sqrt{m}$).

So since $\alpha$ can not be zero or a unit, we have the two cases where 1).  $a\neq 0, b\neq 0$.  2).  $a\neq \pm 1, b\neq 0$.  Therefore $a\ge 2, b\ge 1$.  Now

$N(\alpha)=\alpha\bar{\alpha}=(a+b\sqrt{m})(a-b\sqrt{m})=a^2 -b^2m$.  By our given conditions, we see that $N(\alpha)\neq 0$ or $1$  Now I have to show that $|N(\alpha)|>1.$  I was thinking contradiction, so suppose that there exist an $a,b$ such that $|a+b\sqrt{m}|\le 1$.  Then
$$-1\le a^2+b^2m\le 1$$
However, with $m\ge 2$ this is impossible unless either $a=b=0$ or $a=1, b=0$.  But these cannot be since we have restricted these conditions in the initial problem.  Therefore
$|N(\alpha)|>1$.

Is this the correct way of solving this particuluar problem?  ( I think I worked it out while I was typing, but any verification would be helpful....)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: They are not necessarily of the form $a+b\sqrt{m}$ with $a$ and $b$ integers, example $m=5$. But the norm of an agebraic integer is always an integer. So if it has absolute value not equal to $0$ or $1$, it must have absolute value greater than $1$.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean with $m=5$.  How are elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ not of the form $a+b\sqrt{5}$ with rational integers $a,b$?

Comment: The *integers* of ${\bf Q}(\sqrt5)$ are not of the form $a+b\sqrt5$ with $a,b$ integers. $(1+\sqrt5)/2$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: Okay, I get that since it is a solution of $x^2-x-1=0$.  But the book says they are "rational integers". It is quoted in Niven as "In algebraic number theory, $0, \pm 1, \pm 2,...$ are often referred to as $rational integers$ to distinguish them form other algebraic integers that are not rational".  I think specifically for this problem

Comment: Oh, I think I found it, because $5\equiv 1\pmod{4}$....So should I be doing the proof by cases then to accommodate the different forms of $m$? (i.e., $1\pmod{4}, 3\pmod{4},...$)

Comment: You can manage all the proofs at once by recalling that $N(\alpha)$ is really the index of the ideal generated by $\alpha$, which is straightforward from first principles, independent of the field in question. I actually thing hard computations in that case confuse the issue and make it harder than it needs to be, when the general case is so simple to prove.

Comment: @Adam, I don't think Niven's book discusses such things as the index of an ideal.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are right.  The book hits many topics and there is certainly a bit of abstract throughout, through rings, fields, etc, but there is nothing about the index of an ideal.

Comment: Chapter 9? Yeah, I don't recall ever seeing the word "ideal" in that book, either as a noun or an adjective.

Comment: Ah, no wonder then. I haven't read Nivens. Thanks for the heads up, @Gerry Myerson.

Comment: @Adam, that's no reason to delete your answer. Even if it's not (immediatley) helpful to OP, it might be helpful to others (or to OP in the future).

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks again for the heads up. The answer is undeleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. For elements of the field, $k$, we have that

> $$|N(\alpha)|=[\mathcal{O}_k:(\alpha)]\tag{$*$}.$$

Iff the index in the ring is $1$ is $\alpha$ a unit when $\alpha$ is an integer of $k$.

*Proof of the formula $(*)$*:

We know that the map $m_\alpha:x\to\alpha x$ is a linear transformation of the field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ to itself which has determinant $N(\alpha)$ by definition of the norm down to $\Bbb Q$. Since $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, $m_\alpha$ takes the integer ring, $\mathcal{O}_k$ into itself as a $\Bbb Z$-module of rank $2$, and indeed the image is just $\alpha\mathcal{O}_k=(\alpha)$. However the index of that ideal is exactly the determinant of the matrix because $\mathcal{O}_k$ is a finitely generated, free $\Bbb Z$-module, hence $|N(\alpha)|=1\iff (\alpha)=\mathcal{O}_k$. That $N(\alpha)\in\Bbb Z$ for all algebraic integers is a byproduct of the fact that $m_\alpha\in GL_{[k:\Bbb Q]}(\Bbb Z)$ is a matrix with integer coefficients, when $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_k$.

---

As a side note, it's straightforward to show in fact, that $N^L_{\Bbb Q}(\alpha)=N_{\Bbb Q}^k(\alpha)^{[L:k]}$ from the definition of the norm, whenever $\alpha\in k\subseteq L$, and that the charateristic polynomial of $m_\alpha$ in $L$ is just the $[L:k]$th power of the characteristic polynomial in $k$, so that you can really just assume that the polynomial for $m_\alpha$ is the minimal one, since $|x|^n\le 1\iff |x|\le 1$ as far as sizes are concerned. I mention it because--in your case--it's easier to see more concretely why the constant term in the characteristic polynomial of that matrix exactly matches the ad hoc definition as $a^2-mb^2$.